# Search a pattern if exists

Tags: python

I have a Python list that states strings. If any other string contains any words mentioned in the list then exclude that other string for further processing:

```
print ignore_list
['name', 'wait', 'delete']
```

I have other string that is of below format:

```
My Name is xxxx
OR
Hello
OR
This is to be deleted
etc
```

Now I need to exclude all strings that has str embedded as mentioned in ignore_list. My code is something like below:

```
if string_val and not string_val in ignore_list:
print string_val
```

But the upper code seems actually comparing some thing like:

```
if "This is to be deleted" and "This is to be deleted" in 
['name', 'wait', 'delete']:
print string_val  ==> prints "This is to be deleted" as the same is not present in the list
```

How can I achieve the same i.e. If any list of string values is embedded in string then it should be ignored else processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) with generator expression that checks membership for each word on ignore list:

```
if all(x not in s for x in ignore_list):
    print s
```